# Lighthouse (PWA) shows "Eliminate render-blocking resources" for Bootstrap CSS, but I'm using "async"

Tags: progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

Here's the section from the Lighthouse report:

[image]
And this it the webpage in question:
https://idealofficetemperature.web.app/

Here's the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" async>
```

So what am I doing wrong? I'm using **async** - I thought that would satisfy that Lighthouse validation.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract all of the critical items and place those inline
Here is an article from last week that explains that
https://web.dev/extract-critical-css

Two other things that may work
Both work for me

1. Change ***async*** to ***lazyload***
   According to CanIUse, it's not supported, but seems to work for lighthouse?
   https://caniuse.com/#search=lazyload
2. OR add this instead of async
   media="nope!" onload="this.media='all'"

Found that solution here
https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html